# Sorting List leads to conversion 'void' error

Tags: c#, .net

Can't figure out why I get a void error with this attempt to sort my list.  parameterList is a dictionary originally then I convert it to a generic list then try sorting.  I want back the list as a generic list as you can see:

```
   List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> sortedList = parameterList.ToList().Sort((left, right) => left.Key.Equals(right.Key, StringComparison.Ordinal)
                                                    ? string.Compare(left.Value, right.Value, StringComparison.Ordinal) 
                                                    : string.Compare(left.Key, right.Key, StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

Error: "`Cannot convert source type 'void' to target type List<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,string>>`

What is this void it's talking about....??

**UPDATED**

The list sorting still won't sort, using any of the sugestions or my original sort code that I grabbed from http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/csharp/OAuthBase.cs

So this is how I have it:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> authParamsNonNormalized = new Dictionary<string, string> {
                                                                                                  {Constants.OAuthConsumerKey, consumerKey},
                                                                                                  {Constants.OAuthSignatureMethodKey, methodType},
                                                                                                  {Constants.OAuthTimestampKey, timeStamp()},
                                                                                                  {Constants.OAuthTokenKey, accessToken},
                                                                                                   {Constants.OAuthNonceKey, nonce},
                                                                                                  {Constants.OAuthVersionKey, Constants.OAuthVersion}
                                                                                              };
```

Then I convert it to a Generic list with the ToList()t as this was an incoming dictionary to my method that contains this code:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> sortedParamList = parameterList.ToList();
            sortedParamList.OrderBy(p => p.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal)
                                    .ThenBy(p => p.Value, StringComparer.Ordinal).ToList();
```

when I check sortedParamList, it's still in the same order...nothing happened.

UPDATED:

crap, yea I screwed up the last one, here is the working code:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> sortedParamList = parameterList.OrderBy(p => p.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal)
                            .ThenBy(p => p.Value, StringComparer.Ordinal).ToList();
```

Comment: I'd consider writing a comparer for that since that's a really complicated comparison.  That way you can get that nasty looking code out of that line and in its own place.

Comment: Nooo… `OrderBy` *returns* the sorted enumerable; it doesn’t sort it in-place like `Sort` does. I know this may be confusing for many. You need to assign the result of the `parameterList.OrderBy` operation to your target variable. See my example below.

Comment: yea I probably will create a utility method later on...for now this is just code to try to get this working, this is a new wrapper I'm building, then I'll go back and clean it up.

Comment: Doug I tried that also, did not work.  Problem is the way you stated it infers that you said it does sort in place by the wording you gave me "The following LINQ is semantically equivalent, but significantly clearer:"

Comment: Could you paste the corrected code?

Comment: You’re right; it may have been misleading. I used the term ‘LINQ’ vaguely to refer to the entire statement (including the assignment). LINQ proper is *never* performed in-place; all its extension methods return the result (often as a query that is then evaluated on demand) without altering the original.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) does not returned the sorted list; rather, it performs the sort “in-place”, altering the list instance on which it is called. You probably mean to use:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> sortedList = parameterList.ToList();
sortedList.Sort((left, right) => left.Key.Equals(right.Key, StringComparison.Ordinal)
    ? string.Compare(left.Value, right.Value, StringComparison.Ordinal)
    : string.Compare(left.Key, right.Key, StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

The following LINQ is semantically equivalent, but significantly clearer:

```
List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> sortedList =
    parameterList.OrderBy(p => p.Key, StringComparer.Ordinal)
                 .ThenBy(p => p.Value, StringComparer.Ordinal)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: yea I finally see that now...duh.

Comment: for some reason either of the above sorts my list.  I still end up with an unordered list after the sort.

Comment: Are you sure you’re accessing `sortedList` to check, not `parameterList`? If yes, could you post some example code of how you’re initializing `parameterList`?

Answer (score 2):

All of the overloads of [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3da4abas.aspx) sort in place and don't return anything.

Perhaps [`IEnumerable<T>.OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx) would be more appropriate for what you're trying to do.

Comment: It'd certainly be a lot better than creating a list _then_ sorting.  It should be sort the collection and put the results into a list.

Answer (score 2):

The [Sort](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) method is an instance method of `List` and sorts the current instance, thus does not return a list.

You'll need to split up your code.

```
List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> sortedList = parameterList.ToList();
sortedList.Sort((left, right) => left.Key.Equals(right.Key, StringComparison.Ordinal)
                                     ? string.Compare(left.Value, right.Value, StringComparison.Ordinal) 
                                     : string.Compare(left.Key, right.Key, StringComparison.Ordinal));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.Sort((left, right) => ...
```

the `Sort` method is `void`, and you can't put it inside a List<...>